# Dropdown image change with link with submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like the image to change based on the dropdown selection, then directed to the URL also associated with the option when submitted.

So, there are two 'values' for each option, the image and the URL. The Image changes instantly and the URL is where the selection is directed to on submit.

I had the image change working, then added the script for a link and the href which did not work.

```
<select onchange="$('#imageToSwap').attr('src', this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
    <option value="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/650647649985646593/FEed4zzM_400x400.jpg" selected="" href="detroitcanvas.co">Choice 1</option>
    <option value="https://news.artnet.com/app/news-upload/2020/01/Jackie-Saccoccio-256x256.png" href="twitter.com">Choice 2</option>
    <option value="https://art-media.s3.amazonaws.com/media/public/tags/tag_animal%20art/2019-11-20T194138.3524830000.thumb.jpeg" href="instagram.com">Choice 3</option>
    </select>
    <br><br>
    <img id="imageToSwap" class="profile" src="http://cdns2.freepik.com/free-photo/facebook-logo_318-49940.jpg">
    <a href="javascript: submitform()">Submit</a>
```

```
<script>document.getElementById('my_selection').onchange = function() {
    window.location.href = this.children[this.selectedIndex].getAttribute('href');}</script>
```

Comment: Not seeing a clear question for a clear solution.

Comment: Hey GetSet, I would like a dropdown menu where where the image changes based on selection. Then, when the option has been selected, the submit button directs to the link associated with the option.

Comment: Thats at least *two* behaviors but im seeing zero code.

Comment: I had used the wrong coding forumla, That fix it for ya?

Answer (score 0):

You can use data attributes in each option for additional values, and key your JS to use them, *e.g.*, this pseudocode:

```
<option data-src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/650647649985646593/FEed4zzM_400x400.jpg" selected="" value="detroitcanvas.co">Choice 1</option>

<script>
document.getElementById('my_selection').onchange = function() {
image.src = this.children[this.selectedIndex].dataset.src;}

onsubmit uses the selected option value 
</script>
```